# There is any way I can split a word into letters and put every word in a separate value of an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, split

I am making an alphabetical sound sorter and I need to break down a string of letters in a way that each letter is a value of an array

something like this

```
MyWord = "A B C"

Array[0] == "A"
Array[1] == "B"
Array[2] == "C"
```

there is any way to do this in a simple way?

Comment: Did you try `MyWord.split()` for instance?

Comment: Does your "word" and "string of letters" really have spaces?

Answer (score 0):

```
#If there is space in between
MyWord = "A B C"
Array = MyWord.split()
print(Array) #output: ['A', 'B', 'C']

#If there is no space in between
MyWord = "ABC"
Array = [x for x in MyWord]
print(Array) #output: ['A', 'B', 'C']

#The above one-liner is equivalent to
MyWord = "ABC"
Array = []
for x in MyWord:
    Array.append(x)
print(Array) #output: ['A', 'B', 'C']
```